# Magento2 Category thumbnail image not uploaded?

Tags: magento2

I want to create category thumbnail image  in magento2  after I upload image and save image is not save its show blank my controller

```
<?php

namespace Company\Categorylist\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Thumbnailimage;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
* Class Upload
*/
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
   /**
    * Image uploader
    *
    * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader
    */
   protected $imageUploader;

   /**
    * Upload constructor.
    *
    * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
    * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    */
   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
       \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
   ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
       $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
   }

   /**
    * Check admin permissions for this controller
    *
    * @return boolean
    */
   protected function _isAllowed()
   {
       return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Magento_Catalog::categories');
   }

   /**
    * Upload file controller action
    *
    * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
    */
   public function execute()
   {
       try {
           $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('thumbnail');

           $result['cookie'] = [
               'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
               'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
               'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
               'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
               'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
           ];
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
           $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
       }
       return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
   }
}
```

and my di.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider" type="Company\Categorylist\Model\Category\DataProvider" />
        <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">catalog/tmp/category</argument>
            <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">catalog/category</argument>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Company\Categorylist\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Thumbnailimage\Upload">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

please look my code and support to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

this is magento issue and here is link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5438 
if you looking solution here is it. https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/5978/files