# Product Category Thumbnail Image Not Working

Tags: magento2, product, thumbnail, category-image

I'm running in an issue on `Magento EE 2.2.3` with `category thumbnail images`.  Normal `category images` seem to upload just fine, and (as shown in the two pictures below, first shows it lets me upload the image, second is after save), I can initiate the thumbnail upload, but on submit, but after refreshing the page its simply gone.  There are no errors and nothing useful in the log that I have found, and no notifications in the interface.

I found a similar issue here [Magento2 Category thumbnail image not uploaded?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158991/magento2-category-thumbnail-image-not-uploaded) but from what I can tell the fix there is already part of the more recent version that I have (I might be wrong on that, not entirely sure).

Is there anything I can do to debug this effectively?  I would like to have `category thumbnails` in use in the menu system but can't with this not working.

[image]
[image]